# CSS files not loading from AWS S3

Tags: html, css, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I include my CSS files in the header:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://cdn.website.com/base.css">
```

In the S3 interface under Properties-->Metadata-->

```
Key: Content-Type
Value: text/css
```

Permissions are granted to `Everyone` with `Open/Download`

Still not working.

Comment: And you are sure cdn.website.com is pointing to your bucket, right?

Comment: You need to split the problem down the middle and look both directions.  Can you access `http://cdn.website.com/base.css` directly, with your browser?  If not, look to S3 and DNS.  If so, load your page with the browser's developer tools enabled and see if the file actually gets requested, or if errors are logged.  Each possibility leads to a very different choice for the appropriate next step. Is your web site http, or https?

Comment: Yes the page is accessible `http://cdn.website.com/base.css`, but it does not load when called in the `<link>` tag. I'm using http

Comment: Is the problem solved? I am having the same issue.

Comment: Any luck with this issue? having same issue

Comment: Maybe there is a problem with CORS (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/de_de/AmazonS3/latest/dev/cors.html)

Comment: In AWS s3 bucket - I replaced the css file but it's not reflecting, Please help anyone How remove caching from s3

Answer (score 0):

The problem is determining the path to the static content of the application (it depends on path the application starts olso)

#### Solutions are:

1. Start application from root application path

   example: ApplicationName path=/home/ec2-user/site then need

   ```
    cd /home/ec2-user/site && ./ApplicationName
   ```
2. Configure path for method .UseWebRoot(path_to_static_content)